# Kali Linux and base distribution?

Tags: linux, linux-distributions

I need to setup a VM for [Kali Linux](http://www.kali.org/).

I've looked around Kali's website, but I can't determine what the base distro is. Does anyone know what distro its based upon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kali Linux is a Debian-derived Linux distribution designed for digital forensics and penetration testing. It is maintained and funded by Offensive Security Ltd. It was developed by Mati Aharoni and Devon Kearns of Offensive Security through the rewriting BackTrack, their previous forensics Linux distribution.[1]

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kali_Linux